# How do describe "each day", "once a week" or "every second year"?

Tags: word-choice, recurring-events

I want to describe a repetition for an event.

A single event can have multiple repetitions because it can occur e.g. every second week (a regular happening) + once a year (special annual occasion).

So each repetition has its own:

- start date and time
- end date and time
- exclusion - list of dates when an event is skipped (holidays etc.)
- **something** like "day/month/year/..."
- **something** like "second, third, ..."

I'm thinking about which is the best to describe the properties of a repetition:

I know that for "weekly/monthly/yearly/..." I should choose *frequency*.

I wonder if for "every X" I can use *interval* or maybe *period*?

So far, I found two related topics:

- [Daily, weekly, monthly, yearly, once (?)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/242158/daily-weekly-monthly-yearly-once)
- [What is the collective term for "Daily", "Weekly", "Monthly" and "Yearly"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/326819/what-is-the-collective-term-for-daily-weekly-monthly-and-yearly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a software developer that also frequents the English stack exchange, are you asking a naming convention related question? If so, you should check out naming conventions of frameworks such as [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) or [Quartz.NET](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/).

I frequently have used these terms when defining a **Schedule**, which I assume is what you're naming a "Repetition".

> something like "second, third, ..."

I have used Interval for this, according to definition #2 [here](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/interval) which states "a period of temporary cessation; pause".

"Period" is a length of time, while "Interval" refers to the time between two actions.

> I know that for "weekly/monthly/yearly/..." I should choose frequency.

I would agree with this conclusion. Frequency being how often the schedule should be repeated. Or "rate of occurrence" according to definition #2 [here](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/frequency).

So in summary:

- **Frequency** defines how often the Schedule gets repeated (daily, weekly, monthly, etc).
- **Interval** defines how much time should pass between actions (every X hours, every X days, every X months, etc).